# How to switch off suggestion mechanism of language tool?

Tags: python, languagetool

I am using languageTool with python. But it is quite slow when I want to proceed really long text or lot of texts. I keep on reading how long is the suggestion mechanism, I actually do not need any suggestion, I am interested only on rule_id and category.

Does someone know how to turn off this suggestion mechanism in order to gain some processing power ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source:](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/language_tool/src/3ff98c7d9d74be3ea1707340bca47fb5434c1837/language_tool/__main__.py?at=default) It looks like the closest argument is `-a`, but that is only to enable automatic application of suggestions, not disable suggestions. It is open-sourced so you could edit it yourself and and an argument.

```
  parser.add_argument("file",
                    help="plain text file or “-” for stdin")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--encoding",
                    help="input encoding")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--language", metavar="CODE",
                    help="language code of the input or “auto”")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mother-tongue", metavar="CODE",
                    help="language code of your first language")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--disable", metavar="RULES", type=get_rules,
                    action=RulesAction, default=set(),
                    help="list of rule IDs to be disabled")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--enable", metavar="RULES", type=get_rules,
                    action=RulesAction, default=set(),
                    help="list of rule IDs to be enabled")
parser.add_argument("--api", action="store_true",
                    help="print results as XML")
parser.add_argument("--version", action="version",
                    version="LanguageTool {} ({})"
                            .format(language_tool.get_version(),
                                    language_tool.get_build_date()),
                    help="show LanguageTool version and build date")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--apply", action="store_true",
                    help="automatically apply suggestions if available")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--spell-check-off", dest="spell_check",
                    action="store_false",
                    help="disable spell-checking rules")
return parser.parse_args()  parser.add_argument("file",
                    help="plain text file or “-” for stdin")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--encoding",
                    help="input encoding")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--language", metavar="CODE",
                    help="language code of the input or “auto”")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mother-tongue", metavar="CODE",
                    help="language code of your first language")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--disable", metavar="RULES", type=get_rules,
                    action=RulesAction, default=set(),
                    help="list of rule IDs to be disabled")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--enable", metavar="RULES", type=get_rules,
                    action=RulesAction, default=set(),
                    help="list of rule IDs to be enabled")
parser.add_argument("--api", action="store_true",
                    help="print results as XML")
parser.add_argument("--version", action="version",
                    version="LanguageTool {} ({})"
                            .format(language_tool.get_version(),
                                    language_tool.get_build_date()),
                    help="show LanguageTool version and build date")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--apply", action="store_true",
                    help="automatically apply suggestions if available")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--spell-check-off", dest="spell_check",
                    action="store_false",
                    help="disable spell-checking rules")
return parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Thank, I already check in the code. The closest option is actually -s since it disable spell-checking and in the same time suggestion. However I'd like to keep the speel checking on.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still wonders, `language-tool-python` has the configuration option `maxSpellingSuggestions`.

However, despite the default value being `0` (and the same behavior is noticed after setting this to `0` when initializing the tool), I have noticed that the code runs noticeably faster (almost 2 times faster) when this parameter is actually set to `1`.

Example initialization:

```
import language_tool_python

language_tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US', config={'maxSpellingSuggestions': 1})
```